# Unable to access an XsltListViewWebPart in codebehind!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have created a XsltListViewWebPart using the designer and copied the same page to a site page. This has been deployed from the visual studio. Now, I have added a code behind file. But, I'm not able to get the XsltListViewWebPart inside the code behind. I need to set some properties using the code behind. Getting null for the below mentioned code. How can I get that ?

```
var cntl = this.FindControl("g_e4c4ddc3_e234_43d2_9a4b_a1c391d69f17") as XsltListViewWebPart;
```

Answer (score 3):

To get a WebPart you use the [Limited Web Part Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx)

> The [SPWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.spwebpartmanager) manages all the Web Part controls, functionality, and events that occur on a webpage..

For example

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart current in wpm.WebParts)
    {
        if (current is XsltListViewWebPart)
        {
        }
    }
}
```